# Unable to consolidate data from Salesforce using salesforce connector and aggregate in wso2

Tags: iterator, wso2, salesforce, aggregate, aggregator

I'm trying to extract data from salesforce using iterator and finally consolidate the data using aggregator.

```
<property name="Result" scope="default">
            <Result xmlns=""/>
        </property>
        <iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor" continueParent="true" expression="//sfdc:iterator" id="SFDCData" sequential="true">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <salesforce.queryMore configKey="MySFConfig">
                        <batchSize>200</batchSize>
                    </salesforce.queryMore>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <result xmlns="">$1
                            </result>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/*"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
        <aggregate>
            <correlateOn expression="SFDCData"/>
            <completeCondition>
                <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Result" expression="//result">
                <respond/>
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>
```

When i try to invoke the service using postman, it shows timeout error. "Could not get any response".

All I need is to consolidate the data from Iterator and project back to the end user.
If you have any lead or idea on this, please drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide Sample Request XML?
From your code i can analyse that in the XML there are multiple occurrences of element "sfdc:iterator" and this you are passing in iterator which means that if  there are 5 elements then the message will be split into 5 and then sent to salesforce.But may i know the reason of using payload mediator?
Is it possible to remove the payload mediator and execute the request. 
Upon that as you have made this sequential so it's good practice to log so that you can analyse where the fault is happening

Comment: I used payload to reconstruct the response from salesforce inside result tag, which I wanted to fetch externally.
As you asked, I am not passing any input XML, rather the service starts with invoking a salesforce connector. 
Once the connector is invoked, it provides a response which is passed to iterator to extract remaining responses.

Comment: Have you logged the response which is coming from salesforce API?I Would recommend to remove the payload mediator and then testing the service

Comment: I tried without payload...problem i am facing is that, service is not responding with aggregate added...

Comment: Can you remove the respond mediator and put it at the end of the sequence

Comment: In iterate mediator you haven't mentioned "attachPath", first you need to mention complete attachPath followed by  expression .        
     " <iterate xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
         preservePayload="true"
         attachPath="<Mention the path>"
         expression="<Mention the path>/<element>"
         id="SFDCData"> "